# Running a vba macro in word doc (that is already open) from vbscript or batch file

Tags: vba, batch-file, vbscript

Before getting into the main problem, it must be addressed that it is absolutely necessary that the macro be tripped as a result of the vbscript. This is because I have a word macro that trips a batch script (which accesses our AD directory). That batch scrip trips a vbscript which is supposed to trigger another macro from the already open word file.

For running the macro, here is what I currently have:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set a = objWord.Documents.Open("my path\my.docm")
objWord.Run "Accepted"
```

The problem is, this script causes a new version of the already open file to open and the macro is executed on that file. How do I get the macro to run on the already open file?

Also to be noted, the macro that I'm trying to run is a simple color change of an active control text box (this is the original active control which sets off the macro based on user input):

```
Private Sub Accepted()
CWID_Input.BackColor = &H80FF80
End Sub
```

Also, if there is a way to run the macro from a batch file, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateObject()` will always create a new instance - you want

```
Set objWord = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
```